# ImportError: Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, tflearn, scriptengine

I am trying to write Python script in Java using ScriptEngine. But when I import tflearn module it gives me following errors.

```
javax.script.ScriptException: ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: cannot import name multiarray
 in <script> at line number 1
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.scriptException(PyScriptEngine.java:222)
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:59)
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:31)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at com.ultimatix.bot.JavaRunCommand.main(JavaRunCommand.java:48)
Caused by: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<script>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\tflearn\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import config
  File "D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
```

I also tried to import some different package like sys, pickle. They are getting imported successfully.

Python version: 3.5.4
OS: Window 7 - 64 bits

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is written in Fortran and compiled to binary. For that reason, it is not compatible to be ran on the JVM. The other packages you are importing are implemented in pure python.

CPython, the standard python implementation, has done a lot of work to stay compatible at the binary level. Numpy arrays have the same memory layout as C arrays, which do not have the same memory layout as Java arrays. As you go deeper into python there are a lot more incompatibilities as to why it won't work.

Comment: Thanks Leland for the answer. Is there any work around of such incompatibilities?

Comment: @AnkushBandil answers take valuable time for responders; since the answer is arguably useful, kindly accept it

Comment: @AnkushBandil clearing doubts is OK, as long as these doubts do not constitute a new question; and in any case, I didn't say anything about it, just reminded something that new users, like you, very often neglect